# Retrieve Application Insights association with app service through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I need to get the list of azure application insights associated withe azure resources through powershell. Can anyone help with the query?

Comment: please let me know if you have more issues. And if it works, please help mark it as answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, one azure web app can only associates one application insights.

If you enable the application insights from azure portal -> azure web app -> Application insights, then in the settings -> configurations of the azure web app, there is an environment variable "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY".

[image]

1.If you just want to get the instrumentation key of app insights, just use the code below(az module, you can change it to azureRm module if you need):

```
$myweb = Get-AzWebApp -Name "your_website_name"

$myappInsights = $myweb.SiteConfig.AppSettings.GetEnumerator() | where {$_.name -eq "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"}

$myappInsights.Value
```

2.If you want to get the name of application insights, after get the instrumentation key from above step, you need use loop to get the name:

```
$appinsights = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components"  -ExpandProperties | select -ExpandProperty Properties | select name, InstrumentationKey

$appinsights | where {$_.InstrumentationKey -eq "the instrumentation key"}
```